# Cannot create an Uri

Tags: c#

I'm working with an API that return a json which contains this link:

`\"\/players\/samir-handanovic\/17974\/\"`

so as you can see the structure of this json is pretty bad, so I used this method for unescape it:

```
string newLink = Regex.Unescape(oldLink);
```

this will return this link: `/"/players/samir-handanovic/17974/"`

I want create an uri that have a prefix, so I did:

```
Uri link = new Uri("https://myendpoint.com", newLink);
```

but this will return a `%22` at the end, in particular the `AbsolutePath` is : `/%22/players/samir-handanovic/17974/%22`

what I did wrong?

Comment: Looks like the leading quote, due to being escaped, is being included. %22 = "

Comment: Get rid of the /" nonsense by trimming the start and end by 2 chars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per URI encoding, %22 is coded form of double quote(")
So, you must remove double quotes from around the string newLink as

```
newLink= newLink.Replace("\"", string.Empty).Trim();
Uri link = new Uri("https://myendpoint.com", newLink);
```